# Rotational Potential Energy of a Hamster Wheel

Tags: potential-energy, rotational-kinematics

## Background

(unimportant back story)A colleague of mine showed me what i considered flawed statistics, that Internet Explorer had faster Index and array functions than Chrome(we are software developers...FWIW I'm not proud that this is what we talk about either)  the graphs showed was in operations per seconds.

I replied by trolling him with an example of a Hamster in a Hamster Wheel, saying *Sometimes more work, isn't always faster* . on the flawed premise that $S=d/t$ for $0$ $d$, and $(PE_{initial} + KE_{initial}) + W = (PE_{final}+ KE_{final})$ where $KE = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$ are correlated.

The basics of the equation make sense to me. However, apparently I've trolled myself, because i believe that the Potential Energy of the hamster wheel remains constant across the equation, but i don't believe it has 0 $PE$, I'm just not sure how to calculate the constant amount of $PE$ latent in a Hamster Wheel?

## Research

I like to show that i've done some work, I've done some searching on Rotational Potential Energy, i've found a few results such as $PE = T_{av} \times θ$ but this seems specific to rotational $PE$ of a spring, which should not factor into a Hamster Wheel, I've found loads of simple examples of rotational $KE$ and Inertia like this site

https://www.boundless.com/physics/rotational-kinematics-angular-momentum-and-energy/conservation-of-energy/conservation-of-energy-in-rotational-motion/

## Summary and Question

If a Hamster Wheel has inherent and constant Potent Energy as I believe, how would i calculate it, for a hamster wheel of a given size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potential energy is energy of a position or orientation relative to other positions or orientations.

For example, if the hamster wheel is on a table, it will have more gravitational potential energy than if it is on the floor upon which the table is standing.

If the hamster wheel is rotationally symmetric about the axis of rotation, and the axis is not moving, then gravitational potential energy will stay constant (at least to the extent gravity is constant).

There could be potential energy associated with outward stretching of the wheel as it rotates (analogous to potential energy of a stretched spring), but this should be very small.

Comment: Thanks, I guess i supposed there were other forms of potential energy outside of gravitational, for rotational energy, but looking at your explanation I think i was over-complicating it in my head